# Do dynamic meta tags matter in an SPA

Tags: html, server-side-rendering, meta

Obviously meta tags matter in SSR, but once an SPA has fully loaded in the browser, is there any point in dynamically updating the meta tags?

Let me clarify that I'm asking about meta tags in a runtime scenario where they might impact screen readers, browser apps, etc.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an SEO question outside the scope of Stackoverflow. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/seo

Comment: This isn't an SEO question. I already stated that it obviously matters in an SEO scenario. I'm asking if it has any effect OUTSIDE of an SEO scenario. Would it affect bookmarking in various apps, does it have an impact on ARIA etc.

Comment: Then why *tag* it SEO? And what meta tags are you thinking about updating? "Does *widge range of vaguely defined things* have any impact in *broad scenario*?" isn't really a specific enough question for Stackoverflow.

Comment: Apologies. That was a mistake on my part. I'm currently writing a router with meta data capabilities. I'm wondering if there's any point in adding complexity to keep the meta data dynamically updated. I have no idea if it could affect screen readers or other apps if the meta data goes stale.